# How to add a single border for 2 divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css

First thing, sorry if it's a dumb question...
I have created 2 divs, one on the left of the page, the other one on the right.
The problem is, I want to put a single border around the 2 divs (and not 1 border for each div). I just don't know how to target the 2 divs and make the border surround both divs like it was one element.

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="left2">

        <img src="images/mistake.jpg" class="img2"/>

    </div>

    <div class="right2">

        <p>###########</p>

    </div>
```

And here is my css:

```
div.right2 {
    width: 40%; 
    padding: 2% 5% 0 0;
    float: right;
}

div.left2 {
    width: 40%; 
    padding: 2% 0 0 5%;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to put both of the divs in an outer div and then make a border around that.

HTML:
    `<div id="outer">
       <div id = "left"></div>
       <div id = "right"></div>
    </div>`

CSS:
    `#outer {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    #left { ... }
    #right { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can set this border in the 2 divs:

```
div.right2 {
    width: 40%; 
    padding: 2% 5% 0 0;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: none;
}

div.left2 {
    width: 40%; 
    padding: 2% 0 0 5%;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: none;
}
```

And put the divs next to each other, so there will be no border between divs.